# Hash value in the manifest file

Tags: visual-c++

Im tring to create a manifest for my own.dll, i took the manifest file from C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\Manifests for example. In that, below tag was one of the line.`<file name="msvcr90.dll" hashalg="SHA1" hash="e0dcdcbfcb452747da530fae6b000d47c8674671">`

In above tag, hash value was assigned with 40 character. 
  Here comes my doubt, 
1) hash value was auto generated, if not, whats it points to?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is but it's readily apparent that the hash value is the hash value of `msvcr90.dll` computed with the SHA1 hash-algorithm.